# What's the difference between "typeof str" and "typeof(str)" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typeof

What is the difference between these two statements?

```
if (typeof errorMessage !== undefined)
{}
```

and

```
if (typeof (errorMessage) !== undefined)
{}
```

Comment: You don't say ASAP when asking for help.

Comment: Not a valid question...!!!!

Comment: to check if errorMessage is not undefined you do: if(errorMessage !== undefined){

Comment: @HMR it will give you an error `ReferenceError: errorMessage is not defined`

Comment: I see; sorry. If it's a global variable you can do the following:

if(window.errorMessage !== undefined) or use the 'this' context: if(this.errorMessage !== undefined)

Comment: Using `typeof` is much simpler, and protects you from idiot code that overrides the `undefined` variable.

Answer (score 10):

One of them has a pair of entirely superfluous parentheses.

The difference between `typeof foo` and `typeof (foo)` is the same as the difference between `1 + 1` and `(1) + (1)`.

---

An an aside, the `typeof` operator will give you a string, so you should be comparing to `"undefined"` not `undefined`.